# Regex Replace - Based on Char Input

Tags: c#

Lets say we have string:

```
Hello
```

The user enters a char input "e"

What is the correct way of returning the string as the following using a regex method:

```
-e---
```

Code tried:

```
public static string updatedWord(char guess, string word)
    {
        string result = Regex.Replace(word, guess, "-");
        console.writeline(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Just keep an array/list of the letters that have been guessed and do a for loop using string.Replace()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input were `e`, you could build the following regex pattern:

```regex
[^e]
```

Then, do a global replacement on this pattern, which matches any single character which is *not* `e`, and replace it with a single dash.

```cs
string word = "Hello";
char guess = 'e';
string regex = "[^" + guess + "]";
string result = Regex.Replace(word, regex, "-");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This prints:

```
-e---
```

Note that to ensure that we handle regex metacharacters correctly, should they be allowed as inputs, we can wrap the regex pattern above in `Regex.Escape`:

```cs
Regex.Escape(regex)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without Regex, you need to "loop" all characters of the secret word and replace not yet guessed characters with `-`, regex will loop letters also, but c# methods are more comprehensible ;)
You need to keep collection of already guessed letters.

```
public class Guess
{
    private readonly string _word;
    private readonly HashSet<char> _guessed;

    public Guess(string word)
    {
        _word = word;
        _guessed = new HashSet<char>();
    }

    public string Try(char letter)
    {
        _guessed.Add(letter);

        var maskedLetters = _word.Select(c => _guessed.Contains(c) ? c : '-').ToArray();
        return new string(maskedLetters);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var game = new Guess("Hello");

var result = game.Try('e');

Console.WriteLine(result); // "-e---"
```

Comment: I appreciate the alternative methods. Everything helps me learn. 

I was chose regex as it worked with the way I was making a "Dictionary List"